# How to fetch DB data into Json file and create an UI grid using angular js? without using MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs, json, datagridview

I have to populate a database table as a grid view in Html page using Angular JS. I used a cs file and Data access layer to fetch the Json string of the table data. Now how can I process the json string into Html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar requirement but I need to populate a set of fields using json file, to achieve this I have used the angular formly which reads the JSON file and convert it as a Form UI Inputs

You can learn about angular formly [here](http://angular-formly.com/#/)

Create a services in angular js and get the JSON data from the DB and then use angular formly to populate the grid UI dynamically

This is my code which I have created form inputs using angular formly by reading JSON file (this code is for you to get a IDEA)

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="helloController as mycont">
    <div class="container row">
      <form ng-submit="mycont.onSubmit()" name="mycont.form_nme">
        <formly-form model="mycont.test" fields="mycont.testFields">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="mycont.form_nme.$invalid">Submit</button>
        </formly-form>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>


    var app = angular.module('testApp', ['formly', 'formlyBootstrap']);
    app.controller('helloController', function () {
        var fields = this;
      fields.testFields = [{
          key: 'Name',
          type: 'input',

          templateOptions: {
              label: 'Full Name',
              placeholder: 'Enter your Full name',
              required: true
          }
      }, {
          key: 'address',
          type: 'textarea',
          templateOptions: {
              label: 'Address',
              placeholder: 'Enter your address',
              required: true
          }
      }, {
          key: 'city',
          type: 'input',
          templateOptions: {
              label: 'City',
              placeholder: 'Enter your city',
              required: true
          }
      }, {
          key: 'pincode',
          type: 'input',
          templateOptions: {
              label: 'Pin Code',
              placeholder: 'Enter your Pin code',
              required: true
          }
      }];

      fields.onSubmit = onSubmit;

      function onSubmit() {
          alert('form submitted: ' + JSON.stringify(fields.test));
      }
  });
</script>
```